# Error de memoria en C++

Tags: c++, linux

Tengo este código y me sale este error:

> 15981 segmentation fault (core dumped)

¿Qué tengo mal?, es decir en teoría ahí funcionaría la matriz normal , pero me sale error de memoria, no sé si afecte pero estoy en **Linux 20.04**, compilando con g++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace  std;

  int main(){
    int a [3][3] = {
        {1,2,3},
        {1,2,3},
        {1,2,3}
    };
    int i,j = 0;
    while(i < 3){
        while(j < 3){
            cout<< a [i][j];
            j ++;
        }
        cout << "\n";
        j = 0;
        i ++;
    }
    return (1);
 }
```

Comment: No veo errores, y he probado a compilar y ejecutar y no me ha dado ningún segfault. ¿Seguro que el programa que estás ejecutando corresponde a este fuente? Qiuzás lo has modificado y olvidaste recompilar.

Comment: ¡Ah! Ya lo he visto. No has inicializado `i=0`, sólo `j`

Answer (score 2):

No has inicializado `i`. Aparentemente este fallo es inocuo porque te aseguras de que sea menor a tres:

```
int i,j = 0;
while(i < 3){ // No entrará si la 'i' no inicializada es mayor o igual a 3
    while(j < 3){
        cout<< a [i][j];
        j ++;
    }
    cout << "\n";
    j = 0;
    i ++;
}
```

Pero como es un entero (`int`) puede ser un valor negativo; cualquier valor negativo será menor a tres y accederá a una posición de memoria incorrecta. La solución sería inicializar `i`:

```
int i = 0,j = 0;
while(i < 3){
    while(j < 3){
        cout<< a [i][j];
        j ++;
    }
    cout << "\n";
    j = 0;
    i ++;
}
```

Mejor aún, usa bucles `for` de rango:

```
for (const auto &fila : a)
{
    for (const auto &valor : fila)
        cout << valor;
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Por norma general, los bucles `while` se usan cuando no se sabe los ciclos que se requieren, los bucles `for` se usan cuando la cantidad de ciclos es conocida de antemano. En este caso lo que se requería era un `for`.

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7LCsIwEEXXma@4IKiFuqjubPVH1MUQUwm0k9IkbqTfXlOfoMNs5tzDZXTXrXTDchnHmRXdxLOprPOhN9zuichKQMtWlhndSEVv5QLh1viOtQF8OJdEarIYh80pLXZIJl5zK/J1vhlyegP1Ib/OEwxTX@16LLUTn2pjcJjXtmFswRmpVP6fX7lJaIvJS45S2sWAqsIjKOkLFkdZpHugx0e9CbEXFCVhGMc7)</kbd>.